# Message author's mention isn't being found inside of message content

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def autorole_test(ctx):
  print("trying")
  keystring5 = "Here you go!"
  mee6 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Fresh Player")
  channel = client.get_channel(870023245892575282)
  messages = await ctx.channel.history().flatten()
  for msg in messages:
    if str(keystring5) in msg.content:
      if mee6 in ctx.message.author.roles:
        if ctx.message.author.mention in msg.content:
          print("yes")
```

That is my code above ^

The code works fine upon sending "autorole_test" (my command prefix is set to "") until it reaches "if ctx.message.author.mention in msg.content:"

Even though there are clearly messages that fit this criteria of having the message author's mention in the message content. Is there an alternative way to do this that'll actually work or am I doing something wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Message.raw_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=raw#discord.Message.raw_mentions)

> A property that returns an array of user IDs matched with the syntax of <@user_id> in the message content.
>
> This allows you to receive the user IDs of mentioned users even in a private message context.

so the code would be something like this:

```py
    if author2.id in msg.raw_mentions:
```

Comment: Thanks man but I already figured it out, I'll accept your answer anyways! Also, turns out mentions sent by bots are <@id> and mentions sent by normal users are <@!id>

Follow my method if your looking for a way to count messages that look for mentions by normal users.

Comment: I saw your method, doing it the way is the correct way because you can compare multiple users instead of changing the string for each user `if (user1.id or user2.id) in msg.raw_mentions:`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own. The way discord interprets mentions follows as this:
<@!{user-id}>

The way ctx.message.author.mention is interpreted is:
<@{user-id}>

These two obviously do not synchronize, so we need a work-around. To anyone else who encounters the problem, follow this simple code:

```
    author = ctx.message.author.mention
    author2 = author[:2] + '!' + author[2:]
    if str(author2) in msg.content:
```

Comment: You can also simply `if ctx.author.mentioned_in(msg)`, which us a cleaner, better way.